# Sometimes DeviceSubscriptionExpired event is firing on not expired device ids.#PushSharp

Tags: push-notification, pushsharp

I am sending Push notification messages from my asp.net web site to Android and iPhone.I am using push-sharp version is 2.1.2.0-beta lib.I can send push notification messages successfully and having status log for each message along with there Device ID.
I found more that 100 device  which was having DeviceSubscriptionExpired(PushSharp Event). I check those devices on my database, i found those same device id was successfully on the same day.I am suspecting that those devices are not expired but DeviceSubscriptionExpired event is fired for some reason or apple and google server responding with Subcription expired.

I can't figure it out why it is happening. Can anyone please suggest?

Note: My apps are designed such a way that it will request device id on each application start and update the latest device id if it is changed.

Comment: You might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm running into the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a developer certificate, you should check you are using the production if you are sending push to production apps.

Comment: I had checked certificates , those are production .

Comment: you have to check if they are iOS or Android devices, this will help you